# Bamboo build is hanging for 20 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, bamboo, nunit-console

Running Integration tests from AWS Bamboo using NUnit console runner is hanging for 20 minutes and eventually fails the build with the error message

`Force Stop build feature is enabled for current plan. Either Bamboo has detected the build has hung or it has been manually stopped`

`Attempting to generate stack trace and terminate spawned sub-processes of process id:  Unhandled Exception: NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException: Remote test agent exited with non-zero exit code 1 error   26-Oct-2021 20:08:29       at NUnit.Engine.Services.TestAgency.OnAgentExit(Object sender, EventArgs e) error   26-Oct-2021 20:08:29       at System.Diagnostics.Process.OnExited() error   26-Oct-2021 20:08:29       at System.Diagnostics.Process.RaiseOnExited() error   26-Oct-2021 20:08:29       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) error   26-Oct-2021 20:08:29       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) error   26-Oct-2021 20:08:29       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)`

I did give --labels=All in NUnit test runner command which is helpful to know the tests hanging for 20 minutes. But commenting those hanging tests is not helpful as some other test is hanging for 20 minutes again. Commented about 40 Integration tests and increased the memory in AWS CI/CD Bamboo which ran the build successful. But after uncommenting those tests is causing 20 minutes build hang up again. There is no issues running the Integration tests with nunit3-console.exe locally. What is the best way to troubleshoot this issue?